# Bash: exported variable not loaded in sh script

Tags: bash, unix, environment-variables

I have the following test.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "MY_VARIABLE=$MY_VARIABLE"
```

Well, if I execute the following:

```
export MY_VARIABLE=SOMEVALUE
/bin/bash test.sh
```

it prints:

```
MY_VARIABLE=
```

Why the MY_VARIABLE is not read in the test.sh script?

You can reproduce the context [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php) using the following script:

```
touch test.sh
chmod a+x test.sh
echo "#!/bin/sh" >> test.sh
echo "echo "MY_VARIABLE=$MY_VARIABLE"" >> test.sh
export MY_VARIABLE=something
/bin/bash test.sh
```

Comment: The script from the question below "You can reproduce the context here using the following script:" reproduces the problem ("it prints: `MY_VARIABLE=`") but doesn't reproduce the script shown below "I have the following test.sh script:". The script below "I have the following test.sh script:" doesn't reproduce the problem, it prints `MY_VARIABLE=something` as expected.

Comment: Since you say below the problem involves Docker, not the example you posted, perhaps you should update your question to accurately reflect the situation.

Comment: I have found the reason, I accidentally inserted a double CMD command in the Dockerfile, so my variable did never set and the container started without the variable.

Answer (score 3):

In your script to create the context, the line

```
echo "echo "MY_VARIABLE=$MY_VARIABLE"" >> test.sh
```

creates the following line in `test.sh`:

```
echo MY_VARIABLE=
```

if `MY_VARIABLE` was unset before. The expansion of `$MY_VARIABLE` is done in the shell that prepares your context.

If you use single quotes

```
echo 'echo "MY_VARIABLE=$MY_VARIABLE"' >> test.sh
```

the script `test.sh` contains the correct line

```
echo "MY_VARIABLE=$MY_VARIABLE"
```

and prints `MY_VARIABLE=something` as expected.

Comment: In other words, the problem is in the script to reproduce the issue, as it's not reproducing what the question asks.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes and no. The script to reproduce the issue actually reproduces the issue of not showing the value of the variable but it does not reproduce the script shown at the beginning of the question (which does not reproduce the issue).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried your suggestion in the link I have shared and it works. But in a docker container it still not work, the MY_VARIABLE is always empty.

Comment: @AlessandroC What exactly does not work? Your script to reproduce the context with my modification? Your real script?

Comment: I think I have a problem with docker, not with the script.

Comment: Maybe you should describe what exactly you are doing with docker, then someone might be able to help.

Comment: Did you try to source the script like I advised?

Answer (score 0):

Everything works well but if you want your parent process to keep environment update, you must `source` your script:

```
source test.sh
```

Otherwise, changes will only have effect during the execution of your script.

You can consider it the same as sourcing your `~/.bashrc` file.